# Aria happiness- two forms with a checkbox of the same name

Tags: html, wai-aria, wcag2.0

On my page I have two login forms- on in the nav (that is present on any page), and one in the page content. For simplicity of implementing, they are nearly identical, and all inputs have the same `name`.

This works just dandy, but when I have the page scanned with [AXE](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-selenium-java), I get the following message:

```
1) Checkbox inputs with the same name attribute value must be part of a group: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.1/checkboxgroup?application=axeAPI
  a) ["#homeLoginStayLoggedIn"]
    Fix any of the following:
      All elements with the name "stayLoggedIn" do not reference the same element with aria-labelledby
      ARIA group does not have aria-label or aria-labelledby
```

It only seems to have a problem with the checkbox elements. I have tried several ways of fixing, including the `group` role to the surrounding divs, using `aria-label` and `aria-labeledby`, with no fix.

Page form:

```
<form id="homeLogin" class="loginForm card-text">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="homeLoginEmailUsername">Email or Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control loginEmailUsername" id="homeLoginEmailUsername" placeholder="email or username" name="usernameEmail" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="homeLoginPassword">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control loginPassword" id="homeLoginPassword" placeholder="password" name="password" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check" role="group">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input loginStayLoggedIn" id="homeLoginStayLoggedIn" name="stayLoggedIn">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="homeLoginStayLoggedIn" id="homeLoginStayLoggedInLabel" aria-label="homeLoginStayLoggedIn">
                Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitButton">
        Sign in
        <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-link resetButton">Reset</button>
    <div class="form-response">
    </div>
</form>
```

Nav form:

```
<form id="navbarLogin" class="px-4 py-3 loginForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="navbarLoginEmailUsername">Email or Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control loginEmailUsername" id="navbarLoginEmailUsername" placeholder="email or username" name="usernameEmail" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="navbarLoginPassword">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control loginPassword" id="navbarLoginPassword" placeholder="password" name="password" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" role="group">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input loginStayLoggedIn" id="navbarLoginStayLoggedIn" name="stayLoggedIn" aria-labelledby="navbarLoginStayLoggedInLabel">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="navbarLoginStayLoggedIn" id="navbarLoginStayLoggedInLabel" aria-label="navbarLoginStayLoggedIn">
                Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="navbarLoginSubmitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitButton">
        Sign in <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-link resetButton">Reset</button>
    <div class="form-response">
    </div>
</form>
```

### Update

With Graham's answer, I now get the following error, which is what led me down the path of using all the extra aria attributes:

Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input loginStayLoggedIn" id="homeLoginStayLoggedIn" name="stayLoggedIn">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="homeLoginStayLoggedIn">
            Remember me
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error:

```
1) Checkbox inputs with the same name attribute value must be part of a group: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.1/checkboxgroup?application=axeAPI
  a) ["#homeLoginStayLoggedIn"]
    Fix any of the following:
      All elements with the name "stayLoggedIn" do not reference the same element with aria-labelledby
      Element does not have a containing fieldset or ARIA group
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

You can ignore that error message as it doesn't apply to your implementation. However you really need to fix a load of issues with the other `aria` in your example.

### Long answer

This is probably not going to cause any issues in your implementation, but there is a good reason this error is shown.

Generally if you use multiple checkboxes with the same `name` attribute you are submitting that information as an array of options. As such it is expected that these checkboxes are related to each other and so should have a common naming.

Using `aria-labelledby` allows you to associate more than one label. So you would have the "master" label (say "meal options") and then a checkbox specific label (i.e. "extra sauce" or "extra chips").

That way when a user reaches that group of checkboxes they know they function like a multi-select and are related. This is why Axe recommends this as it thinks your inputs should be part of a list of options as they have the same name.

Here is a simplified example with just the key attributes to illustrate this behaviour. The first input would read "Meal options, extra sauce", the second "Meal options, extra chips".

```
<label id="masterLabel">Meal options</label>
<label id="itemLabel1">extra sauce</label>
<input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="masterLabel itemLabel1"/>
<label id="itemLabel2">extra chips</label>
<input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="masterLabel itemLabel2"/>
```

As the items are not actually related in the way Axe thinks they are (as they are in different forms in different locations on the page) this shouldn't cause you any issues.

You correctly associate labels with `for="idOfInput"` and `<input id="idOfInput"` so that part is fine.

### With that being said...

You have fallen into the "add aria everywhere I can" trap and made a few mistakes with some `aria` attributes in your examples.

Firstly your `<label>`s have an aria attribute they shouldn't, `aria-label="homeLoginStayLoggedIn"`. An `aria-label` is used to **overwrite** the semantically derived information in an element. What you have effectively done is try to make the label content "homeLoginStayLoggedIn". Remove this.

As your labels have a 1 to 1 relationship (1 label for 1 input) they do not need an ID.

An ID on a label is useful for `aria-labelledby` as that is looking for the ID(s) of elements to provide the labelling information on the input but in your implementation it is not needed as the association is already there with the `for` and `id`.

`role="group"` is also not needed. As discussed earlier the Axe error is assuming your checkboxes are meant to be submitted together as part of options. You only use `role="group"` to group related controls. Using the meal example you may have controls to change the meal options such as how you want your steak cooked, sauces, sides etc. These are all "meal options" so would benefit from being grouped together.

So with that in mind your final form section would be as follows:-

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="form-check">
         <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input loginStayLoggedIn" id="homeLoginStayLoggedIn" name="stayLoggedIn">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="homeLoginStayLoggedIn">
             Remember me
         </label>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and

```
<div class="form-group" role="group">
     <div class="form-check">
         <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input loginStayLoggedIn" id="navbarLoginStayLoggedIn" name="stayLoggedIn">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="navbarLoginStayLoggedIn">
             Remember me
         </label>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I updated my question with the initial error that I got with just those aria fields though. Any thoughts?

Comment: I explained why you are getting the error, not sure what else I can do to explain it for you,  it is an error that can be ignored in your implementation as it is Axe thinking your two inputs are related as they have the same name. Not sure how else to phrase that to make it clear I am afraid.

Comment: If you want to remove the error just rename one of the inputs and handle it on the backend with an "or" operator.